# How is CVE-2015-7547 impacting Tor/Tails/Tor Browser?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, security, tails

If this is critically impacting Tails, for example, why hasn't there been an immediate upgrade to apply the patch?

Answer (score 2):

Nick Mathewson wrote a [mail](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2016-February/040280.html) to the [tor-talk mailing list](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/) and analysed the situation. He wrote:

> Tor never uses glibc's resolver to make DNS requests for any
>   attacker-controlled addresses. So in order to mount an attack based on
>   the this vulnerability, I think you'd need to successfully take over
>   one of somebody's configured addresses, first by figuring out what
>   they're resolving, and then either by compromising an appropriate DNS
>   server or running an appropriate DNS cache poisoning attack.

So in short it seems quite hard to attack Tor with this vulnerability.

Comment: Don't forget, that running local DNS server is usual necessity when using Tor, so it *can* be affected if glibc is used

Answer (score 0):

It does not affects the software, but *the shared library is affected*. I'm using [CLang](http://clang.llvm.org/), for example, and not affected by it at all =) Take a look [at the Proof of Concept here](https://github.com/fjserna/CVE-2015-7547) and check if you're vulnerable